# God's number for the 3x3x3 Picture Cube

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups, rubiks-cube

I've a small question.

I've read that God's number for the regular 3x3x3 Rubik's cube is 20 and in quarter-turn metric it's 26.

Here are some links:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God%27s_algorithm
2. https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/gods-number/
3. [https://www.cube20.org/](http://www.cube20.org/)

Numberphile Videos: [Rubik's Cube on Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLt5AfwLFPxWJNAdHv8TUCOmj7iKqyHZeg)

Then was wondering; are the numbers different when considering orienting center pieces on picture cubes?

My first instinct is that God's number in that case would be higher, but really; I have no idea.

Any insight, links or feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Could provide (or link to) a definition of God's number?

Comment: the lowest number possible to complete a task.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8115/what-is-gods-number-for-the-rubiks-picture-cube

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot that I posted that.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherMowla :)